# How do I get the dollar sign to show up beside numerical values in printf method?

Tags: java

Here is my code. I want the dollar sign to print beside each value.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < enrollment.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(enrollment.get(i).toString());
        System.out.printf("\tTuition: %17.2f \n",enrollment.get(i).calcTuition());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just embedd the `$` in the format string:

```
System.out.printf("\tTuition: $%17.2f \n",enrollment.get(i).calcTuition());
```

Comment: Note, the [java.util.Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) recommends use of `%n` for platform-specific line separators. Use this instead of `\n`.

Comment: I tried doing this and the dollar sign ended up left-aligned and the numbers right-aligned. Is there any way of getting the dollar sign to stay next to the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a NumberFormat currency instance

```
NumberFormat currencyIntance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

double tuition = enrollment.get(i). calcTuition();
System.out.printf("%8s: %9s%n", "Tuition", currencyInstance.format(tuition));
```

Note, consider avoiding using `\t` and `\n` inside of your printf. Use format specifier width for `\t` and `%n` in place of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enrollment.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(enrollment.get(i).toString());
    System.out.printf("\tTuition: %s \n", String.format("%17.2f", 
                       enrollment.get(i).calcTuition()).trim());
}
```